# Moving a group in QGIS into another group

Tags: qgis, python

I have an existing group in QGIS which I want to move inside another existing group. More specifically, I am trying to write a function which takes a list of group names, and nests each one under the previous. ie:

moveGroups(['group1', 'group2', 'group3])

would result in:

group1

>group2

>>group2

This is what I have so far but it just puts everything at the same level

```
def moveGroups(groupList):

    qgisGroupsRoot = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()

    for groupName in groupList:

        if groupList.index(groupName) == 0:
            continue

        if qgisGroupsRoot.findGroup(groupName):
            group_node = qgisGroupsRoot.findGroup(groupName)
            group_node_clone = group_node.clone()

            parentGroupName = groupList[groupList.index(groupName)-1]

            parentGroupIndex = iface.legendInterface().groups().index(parentGroupName)
            qgisGroupsRoot.insertChildNode(parentGroupIndex, group_node_clone)
```